# Which are good documentaries about environmental impact of livestock industry?

Tags: environment, documentaries, livestock-industry

I've already seen [Cowspiracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cowspiracy) (and I recommend it). Which other documentaries have been made about the impact of livestock industry and how going vegan can alleviate environmental problems?

Comment: While not a livestock industry documentary (that's why I answer in a comment), **Racing Extinction** is a great one and if I remember correctly, it touches the issues of livestock as well. http://racingextinction.com/

Comment: Earthlings - hard to watch, converted my son, a life long vegetarian, to vegan.

Answer (score 5):

I will write down a list that touch this subject and also received a decent rating on IMDB (a vague criteria of a movie/documentary quality):

- [Earthlings](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0358456/?ref_=tt_rec_tti) - I have watched it a long time ago and it focuses mainly on how bad animals are treated in the meat industry, but I think it touches a little the environmental impact of livestock industry
- [Food, Inc.](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1286537/?ref_=tt_rec_tti) - "The film's first segment examines the industrial production of meat (chicken, beef, and pork), calling it inhumane and economically and environmentally unsustainable." ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Food,_Inc.))
- [Vegucated](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1814930/?ref_=tt_rec_tti) - "socio-comical documentary about 3 omnivore New York guys who plan to go vegan for six weeks for weight loss and other health benefits. But during their vegan journey, they uncover the dark side of animal agriculture, and all of a sudden find themselves against the very industry they patronized a few weeks before." ([source](http://www.vegansouls.com/vegan-documentaries))

Also, [Unity (2015)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2049636/) might be of interested, as it is advertised as the sequel of Earthlings.

Other movies that may touch the subject can be found within [this list](http://www.vegansouls.com/vegan-documentaries).

Answer (score 1):

**[Seaspiracy](http://www.fraps.com/)** (2016, free on YouTube, 15 minutes)

Although not specifically focused on the livestock industry, connections are mentioned several times throughout.

- 200,000 sharks are killed *every day* for their fins
- So much fish is ground up into pellets to feed livestock that cows, pigs, and chickens are now the world's leading oceanic predators
- If we want to protect biodiversity in the oceans we must stop fishing altogether

[image: Seaspiracy - Exposing the Fishing Industry]

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me this is a two-part question. One part is a list of documentaries on the impact of the livestock industry, and the other is about how going vegan can alleviate environmental problems.

I have no interest in the livestock industry, so I can't help you with that. I can help you with the "going vegan" part. Good thing is that sometimes these go hand in hand.

I listed my reasons of going vegan (environmental, health and animal well-being) and created a list of vegan documentaries that I update regularly. Some of the documentaries have already been mentioned here, but some weren't.

I would agree that Earthlings, Food, Cowspiracy and Vegucated have a good grasp on the impact of livestock industry. But after watching any of them, you get the question "OK, what I can do, and how can I do it?". So you just have to switch to the second part of your question, which is "how do I go vegan?".

Then you have documentaries such as:

- Fat, Sick and Nearly Dead 1 & 2
- Forks Over Knives
- Food Matters
- Peaceable Kingdom,
- Vegan: Everyday Stories
- What The Health
- Simply Raw: Reversing Diabetes in 30 Day
- Live and Let Live

Entire list of documentaries, their review, trailers and why I become vegan can be found [here](http://www.veganproteinguide.com/best-vegan-documentaries/).