# Documentaries in Spanish about environmental impact of meat industry?

Tags: environment, documentaries, livestock-industry

I've previously asked [which are good documentaries about environmental impact of livestock industry](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/q/508/115). However, since I'm living in a Spanish-speaking country, I'm more interested in which documentaries have been **made, or dubbed, in Spanish**?

Comment: Can you also mention the country you're in?  A documentary produced with a particular country in mind would probably be more relevant to citizens of that country.

Comment: First choice would be documentaries relevant to central america, second choice any latin american country, third choice any other country, including Spain or other "first world" countries.

Comment: Cattle-heavy South American countries like Brazil, Uruguay, and Argentina probably have a very different perception of the livestock industry than countries that don't have such a large livestock industry.  That's probably worth considering.

Comment: So are you asking only about documentaries _in Spanish_, or should they focus on environmental impact of the meat industry _in Spanish-speaking countries_?

Comment: @Turion I never asked about meat industry in spanish-speaking countries. Both title and description refer to documentaries about environmental impact of meat industry that have been made or dubbed in spanish.

Comment: @Attilio, I'm referring to your comment: "First choice would be documentaries relevant to central america, second choice any latin american country, third choice any other country, including Spain or other "first world" countries."

Comment: @Turion I was just answering to the question by Adam Miller.

Answer (score 5):

*A Carne É Fraca* (or *La Carne Es Débil*, "Meat is Weak") is a Brazilian documentary about animal abuse in the meat industry. It has a CC-BY license (you are free to distribute it as long as you don't charge for it) and it is available on [Youtube (with subtitles)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ilD5MrQbUsk).

*Meat The Truth* is more focused on environmental consequences of consuming meat. This movie features strong intertextuality with *[An Inconvenient Truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/An_Inconvenient_Truth)*, since it was made in response to Al Gore's lack of commitment against the meat industry. It is also available on [Youtube (with subtitles)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6u1sXsUkPKI).

Both feature graphic violence against animals and, as such, should be accompanied by a content warning and are not suited for children.

Answer (score 3):

[Cowspiracy](http://cosmosdocumentaries1.blogspot.com/2016/03/cowspiracy-sustainability-secret-2014.html) is a good documentary about the environmental impact of animal agriculture, and it has Spanish subtitles.